# Hit events TPS at specific rate in python

Tags: python, performance

I have a python script that make call to a server at a rate of appx 1800 events/sec.

How do i calculate the wait timings if i have to just hit 100 or 200 events every second?

To elaborate: I am making hits for 16 events for 1 sec and eventually total events/sec = 1800

Regards,

Comment: Could you use os.sleep to create a specific delay between requests to the server?

Comment: Yes, i will be using it but finding out the approximate time for delay is the challenge.